# About $\alpha$-indecomposability.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, model-theory, filters

One defines $\alpha$-indecomposability, for ultrafilters $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$, as: for every $\langle I_\beta:\beta<\alpha\rangle$ with $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}I_\alpha=\kappa$, one can find $s\in[\alpha]^{<\alpha}$ with $\bigcup_{\beta\in s} I_\beta\in\mathcal{D}$.

Now, i want to prove: if $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ is $\mu^{(n)}$-indecomposable, for every $n\geq1$, then:

\begin{equation}
\prod\mu^{(n)}/\mathcal{D}=\bigcup_{\nu<\mu^{(n)}}\prod\nu/\mathcal{D}.
\end{equation}
Here $\mu^{(n)}$ is the $n$th succesor of $\mu$: $\mu^{(0)}=\mu$, $\mu^{(n+1)}=(\mu^{(n)})^+$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What did you try? Also, I'm curious about the notation, is $\mu^{(n)}$ standard for the $n$th successor of $\mu$? I'm more familiar with $\mu^{+n}$. I assume you identify the ultraproducts with their transitive collapses, is that right?

Comment: I do not identify the ultraproducts with their collapses. It came from Prikry's work, On descendingly complete ultrafilters, 1973 pp 6,7. And i wanted to use the indecomposability with $\langle\nu:\nu<\mu^{(n)}\rangle$, but so far nothing. One side of the equality seems trivial. And i don't know how standard is that notation, but that's the only one i knew until now.

Comment: Please state your definition of the ultraproduct then. Do you mean just the quotient via the equivalence relation induced by $D$? Then, equality cannot hold but they might be isomorphic (as structures with the $\varepsilon$-relation also induced by $D$).
Did you notice that if you have $f:\kappa\to\mu^{(n)}$ you can apply indecomposability to $(f^{-1}(\alpha)\mid\alpha<\mu^{(n)})$ and use regularity of $\mu^{(n)}$ to get a bounded $g\colon\kappa\to\mu^{(n)}$ which is $D$-a.e. equal to $f$? I'm not completely sure what you're asking but I'd assume that this should be involved in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reversed inclusion is obvious, so I will just give a proof of the inclusion

\begin{equation}
\prod\mu^{(n)}/\mathcal{D}\subseteq\bigcup_{\nu<\mu^{(n)}}\prod\nu/\mathcal{D}.
\end{equation}

Assume that $f : \kappa \to \mu^{(n)}$ is a function. We shall check that it is bounded almost everywhere with respect to $\mathcal{D}$; that is, we have some $\nu<\mu^{(n)}$ such that
$$\{\xi < \kappa : f(\xi)<\nu\}\in\mathcal{D}.$$

Assume that we know $f$ is bounded almost everywhere with an upper bound $\nu$. Then we have a *bounded function* $g$ such that $[f]=[g]$ and $g(\xi)\le \nu$ for all $\xi$. (How? You can find such $g$ if you are familiar with ultrfilters.) Hence $[f]$ is an element of $\prod \nu/\mathcal{D}$.

Take $X_\alpha = \{\xi<\kappa : f(\xi) < \alpha\}$. Then $\bigcup_{\alpha<\mu^{(n)}} X_\alpha = \kappa$. By $\mu^{(n)}$-indecomposability, there is a $s\subset \mu^{(n)}$ such that $|s|<\mu^{(n)}$ and $\bigcup_{\alpha\in s} X_\alpha \in\mathcal{D}$. We know that $\mu^{(n)}$ is regular for each $n\ge 1$, so $\nu := \sup s < \mu^{(n)}$. Moreover, if $\alpha\in s$ then $X_\alpha \subseteq X_\nu$.

Therefore $X_\nu = \{\xi<\kappa : f(\xi) < \nu\} \in \mathcal{D}$, and so $f$ is bounded almost everywhere.